# How to get the Months for the current year and previous year in java?

Tags: java, sql, datetime

i need to get the current month no and from this till past 1 year month no's to generate a report.

For eg: if today is Feb , so From 02 - 2014 to 03-2013 i need to generate.

```
02 - 2014
01 - 2014
12 - 2013
11 - 2013
.
.
.
03 - 2013
```

I need to generate this. Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Why tagged as SQL? Is there something else you forgot to mention or is the tag wrong?

Comment: Also, it's usually good form to have a go at coding it yourself first.

Comment: `I need to generate this` What stops you? You haven't asked any question yet.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to look at the add method in calendar for example:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class CalendarExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM - yyyy");  
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
      System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }

  }
}
```

generates:

```
02 - 2014
01 - 2014
12 - 2013
11 - 2013
10 - 2013
09 - 2013
08 - 2013
07 - 2013
06 - 2013
05 - 2013
04 - 2013
03 - 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with an example using the third-party open-source [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework. Joda-Time is a popular replacement for the outmoded† java.util.Date & .Calendar classes bundled with Java.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now(); // Current date-time using JVM's default time zone.
DateTime pastDate = null;
for ( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {
    pastDate = now.minusMonths( i );
    String monthNumberAsString = String.format("%02d", pastDate.getMonthOfYear() ); // Pad leading zero if need be.
    System.out.println( monthNumberAsString + " - " + pastDate.getYear() );
}
```

Generates

```
02 - 2014
01 - 2014
12 - 2013
11 - 2013
10 - 2013
09 - 2013
08 - 2013
07 - 2013
06 - 2013
05 - 2013
04 - 2013
03 - 2013
```

---

† [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) brings the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) to supplant the old java.util.Date/Calendar classes. These new classes are inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), and defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Comment: If you are going to answer with a non-standard API (jodatime), it would be good to at least mention that in your answer.

Comment: And perhaps explain why to use a 3rd party API instead of the standard API (which provides exactly the same functionality).

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly 1 year back date you could use :

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(df.format(getPastDate()));

}

public static Date getPastDate(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.*;
class dt
{
    Date d;
    String mon;         
    dt()
    {   d= new Date();
        mon = ""+(d.getMonth()+1)+"";
        System.out.println(" mon is "+);        
    }
    public static void main(String[]avi)
    {     new dt();   }
}
```

this code will return current month

like... use method d.getYear() to get current year

note: mon = ""+(**d.getMonth()+1**)+"";
in this i've added 1 month because this method returns 0 -> for jan, 1 -> for feb etc...